# Javascript: Trying to smooth out custom cursor animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm using a small script on my website which follows user's cursor with a page element. The animation is a little sharp and what I need to do is to apply some kind of transition/keyframes to it.

I have tried to set delay using `window.setTimeout` but it didn't work...
I want to achieve the effect like on this [site](https://www.epicurrence.com/). where the mouse moves smoothly, Is there a way to do it without building a HUGE 50kB library?

```js
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    
    var curX = e.clientX;
    var curY = e.clientY;
     
    document.getElementById('mouse').style.left = curX - 10 + 'px';
    document.getElementById('mouse').style.top = curY - 10 + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
background: orange;
}
#mouse {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: black;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<body style="height">
  <div id="mouse"></div>
</body>
```

I would want the element to move smoothly after the cursor.
At the moment it instantly follows the exact path.

Comment: why not run an cursor image, like in this article https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `transition`:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {

  var curX = e.clientX;
  var curY = e.clientY;

  document.getElementById('mouse').style.left = curX - 10 + 'px';
  document.getElementById('mouse').style.top = curY - 10 + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
}

#mouse {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: black;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: .1s linear
}
```

```html
<body style="height">
  <div id="mouse"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah... I think it covers all my needs, but last time i tried to apply any CSS transitions, it ended up flashing all over the screen... Which is extremely noticeable on my 144Hz screen...

Answer (score 0):

Found a code snippet on CodePen.. see the link below:

https://codepen.io/renatorib/pen/gBLDA

The Javascript code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var mousePos = {};

 function getRandomInt(min, max) {
   return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 }

  $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
    mousePos.x = e.pageX;
    mousePos.y = e.pageY;
  });

  $(window).mouseleave(function(e) {
    mousePos.x = -1;
    mousePos.y = -1;
  });

  var draw = setInterval(function(){
    if(mousePos.x > 0 && mousePos.y > 0){

      var range = 15;

      var color = "background: rgb("+getRandomInt(0,255)+","+getRandomInt(0,255)+","+getRandomInt(0,255)+");";

      var sizeInt = getRandomInt(10, 30);
      size = "height: " + sizeInt + "px; width: " + sizeInt + "px;";

      var left = "left: " + getRandomInt(mousePos.x-range-sizeInt, mousePos.x+range) + "px;";

      var top = "top: " + getRandomInt(mousePos.y-range-sizeInt, mousePos.y+range) + "px;"; 

      var style = left+top+color+size;
      $("<div class='ball' style='" + style + "'></div>").appendTo('#wrap').one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function(){$(this).remove();}); 
    }
  }, 1);
});
```

Maybe that'll help.